# Intended audience for a book?

Tags: books

Is there an intended audience for a book, or intended readers? I want to say the targeted sphere of people that would buy and read the book. I mean, for whom the book was written. How do you say it better? To my ear for some reason audience sounds better

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the “intended readers“ [as target readership or audience.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_audience)”

> a  target audience is the intended audience or readership of a publication, advertisement, or other message catered specifically to said the intended audience.

(Wikipedia)